# Meteor publication iron router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a problem with publishing with iron router.

It acts as if can't access the value from the variable

If i try to replace

```
Meteor.subscribe('singleMatch', id);
```

with

```
Meteor.subscribe('singleMatch', 463358926);
```

it works

here is my code
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8810102

Note: i created a separate variable for this.params, because i couldn't access the attributes

Comment: Try without the underscore in `match_id`

Answer (score 0):

There may be two issues here:

I think `Meteor.subscribe('singleMatch', id)` should be `Meteor.subscribe('singleMatch', id).wait()` so that your subscription is in fact ready before you move on. This may be the culprit you're looking for.

Second, I believe `Meteor.call()` is async, therefore your route can actually execute whether or not you receive an error in your callback.